# Setting up spring-mvc in an application that already use it as a dependency of dependency

Tags: java, spring, apache-flex, spring-mvc, spring-2.5

I did not know how to turn the title, hope this is understandable. I am working on a web-app that have existed for years and is currently in production. This web-app uses spring-flex to display some views and one of the dependency of spring-flex is spring-mvc. I think a relevant link would be [there](http://docs.spring.io/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch02s04.html).

So I have all the dependencies already configured in my pom, and a DispatcherServlet already configured in my web.xml with the exact configuration from the manual (I am not the one who did the integration, I am trying to figuring out how it was done).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>flex_servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>flex_servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

From the link I have provided, we can see that by default when a flex message-broker is configured, the configuration looks like this (although it is nowhere to be seen in the project)

```
<!-- Maps request paths at /* to the BlazeDS MessageBroker -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <value>
            /*=_messageBroker
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Dispatches requests mapped to a MessageBroker -->
<bean class="org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Now that I want to use spring-mvc for other tasks, what should I do?

- Declare another DispatcherServlet or use the same one?
- And If I use the same one, can I just copy-past the above block and complete it to override the default configuration?
- And if I don't use the same one, how will each DispatcherServlet know which HandlerMapping to use since they are supposed to discover it themselves?

thanks for your help

EDIT: for future reference, here are relevant documentations:

- [flex and spring-mvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/index.html#flex-and-spring-mvc)
- [SimpleUrlHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.3/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-urlhandlermapping)
- [Multiple UrlHanlderMappings](http://learningviacode.blogspot.fr/2012/11/using-multiple-url-handler-mappings.html)

Comment: I don't know why but my `Hi!` at the top won't display

Comment: You are lucky your `thanks for your help` is still there. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BlazeDS you define a named service, the DispatcherServlet will use this name to send requests to the proper service.
So to answer your questions:

- Declare another DispatcherServlet or use the same one? **Use the same one**
- And If I use the same one, can I just copy-past the above block and complete it to override the default configuration? **No change needed**
- And if I don't use the same one, how will each DispatcherServlet know which HandlerMapping to use since they are supposed to discover it themselves? **Irrelevant, you use the same one**

Based on our conversation below, the answer from this question might help you aswell:
[Spring MVC: RESTful web services + BlazeDS integration possible in the same web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053388/spring-mvc-restful-web-services-blazeds-integration-possible-in-the-same-web?rq=1)

Comment: Sorry but I finally managed to find the relevant doc and they recommend using two separated DispatcherServlet, although using the same one stay possible http://docs.spring.io/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/index.html#flex-and-spring-mvc

Comment: Your question mentions nothing about using multiple client types.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Currently flex works well. `/messagebroker/*` patterns are served as intended. But I want to set up some controllers of my own on `/springmvc/*` and my question is about how to do that while keeping the other working

Comment: The answer to this question can help you as-well if the docs aren't enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053388/spring-mvc-restful-web-services-blazeds-integration-possible-in-the-same-web?rq=1 I'll update my answer aswell

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for. But I also need to define an handlerMapping since I want all `/springmvc/*.json` request be handled by the same bean. Relevant documentation is here:http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.3/reference/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-urlhandlermapping
But they say that "HandlerMapping beans are automatically detected by the DispatcherServlet" This is why I was wondering how it works in case there are several DispatcherServlet for each one to understand which mappings affects him?

Comment: Ok I have found out. This is due to me being inexperimented with spring. When you declare a servlet named springmvc, it will search for configuration in [/WEB-INF/springmvc-servlet.xml]. If I declare a mapping there, it will be specific to this servlet.
Thanks for your help